# Does hard-coding schema names in procedure calls for Oracle jobs have any performance impact?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, jobs

A database application I'm working with uses Oracle scheduled jobs to perform certain tasks. The DBA insists that hard-coding the schema name in the procedures that organise these jobs improves performance, but I can't see how it makes any difference. (I'm not even sure why it's necessary to have the schema name in there at all - the procedures run by the jobs are always in the same schema as the the job definer.)

Can there possibly be any truth to this? In general, does specifying the schema name make any difference when calling a procedure in the same schema as the connected user?

Comment: There is no performance impact, but it is a sure fail of you have to import that job under a different schema. When job accesses objects in the same schema, there is no need to prefix. In a way your DBA may be right, that prefixing schema name is better for name resolution than synonyms, but in your case it doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no performance impact.